# What's up with the "Have you considered starting a bounty or accepting an answer" tag?

Tags: support

I have this annoying tag attached to one of my questions, for which I have no interest in accepting the one inadequate answer, nor of starting a bounty. What makes this tag appear? Can you make it go away?

Comment: I believe that it will go away in time, but I can't find a reference for that.

Comment: Now it appears on two of my questions! I will wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This message will automatically go away after 60 days.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57707/a-suggestion-of-yes-no-button-in-front-of-this-have-you-considered-accepting-an)

So if nothing worth accepting shows up in that time, you'll at least be rid of it that way.